# Oracle cloud API Gateway authentication function in Java

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions

Dears,

I am trying to write Oracle API Gateway authentication function in Java. Please help if you have any resources or examples.

Thanks,

Jasar

Answer (score 1):

You can refer some of the informations here from OCI function authorisation using an authorizer function.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/APIGateway/Tasks/apigatewayusingauthorizerfunction.htm#creatingauthorizer.

Comment: Thanks @MRz I am looking for Java method signature to implement authentication and authorization. I have done this for AWS api gateway authorizer. But could not find any details on the oc function requirement for gateway authentication.